# Swift NSUserDefault for TableView with Multiple Sections?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nsuserdefaults

I'm currently doing an Xcode Project (SWIFT) and I have a few problems relate to NSUserdefault and prepareforsegue.

I have 2 TableViews. TableView1 has 2 sections: section1 and section2. Here are what I want:

- When I click a random row in section1 in TableView1, TableView2 shows up with number of sections that I want. (for example: I click row 1 then TableView2 shows up with 3 sections, I click row 2 then TableView2 shows up with 4 sections, the number of sections that show up in TableView2 have to be different when I click different rows)
- Same as above for section2 in TableView1

  I use an Array of 2 Arrays to show 2 sections in TableView1.

Sorry if this question is stupid, I'm new to programming so I hope you guys can show me how to do this project. I appreciate it :)

Comment: No need to apologize--asking questions is how you learn. However, your question is missing a lot of important details: You have not described what problems you are having. Do you have any code? If so, what is it doing? Also, it is not clear how `NSUserdefault` and `prepareforsegue` are involved. I recommend you read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Thanks. It's not a problem, I just don't know how to do it. From what I learn, to store data and pass it from a tableview to another View I have to use NSUserDefault and PrepareForSegue. I did an exercise in which I click a button and it stores what I wrote in Textfield and pass it to another ViewController and show up in a lable. I did it and it runs well. Then I want to try a little bit harder excercise like what I sum up above. You don't need to show me the specific code, just show me what steps that I have to make, then I will figure out the code myself. Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

**Background**

In order to make this answer clearer, I am assuming that you have two view controllers, `Table1ViewController` and `Table2ViewController` and they display `Table1` and `Table2`. I assume you know how to wire up the two view controllers in Interface Builder so that you can click on `Table1` and have `Table2ViewController` presented.  As you describe in your question, when a user clicks on a row in `Table1` that determines how many sections there should be in `Table2`. I will not discuss anything related to mapping rows of `Table1` into number of sections for `Table2`.

**The main issue is how to send the chosen number of sections to the `Table2ViewController`.**

You could communicate the information using `NSUserDefaults` as you mention in your question, but that is not how user defaults are intended to be used. The documentation for `NSUserDefaults` says *The defaults system allows an application to customize its behavior to match a user’s preferences.* And gives the following examples: *allow users to determine what units of measurement your application displays or how often documents are automatically saved.* Instead you are designing your application to behave based on a previous user selection.

So if we aren't going to use `NSUserDefaults`, how might we go about this? You also mention the `UIViewController` method `prepareForSeque:sender:`. Its documentation reads: *[s]ubclasses override this method and use it to configure the new view controller prior to it being displayed*.

**Main Approach**

And that's exactly what we want to do. Before `Table2ViewController` is displayed, we want to configure it with the number of sections that `Table2` should have. So let's add a property to `Table2ViewController` as follows (note wherever there is "..." in the following, I am leaving out some of the code):

```
class Table2ViewController: ... {
   var numberOfSections = 0

   func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int
   {
       return numberOfSections
   }

...
...
...

}
```

So now all that remains to do is after the user clicks on a row in `Table1`, we determine how many sections `Table2` should have (*I'm leaving that part unspecified*) and then before `Table2ViewController` is displayed we need to configure `numberOfSections`. We do so in the `prepareForSegue` call.  Something like the following should work:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)
{
  if let selectedIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
    var destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as! Table2ViewController
    destinationVC.nummberOfSections = self.numberOfSectionsFor(selectedIndexPath)
  }
}
```

So we've first determined the index path for the selected row. Then we cast `segue.destinationViewController` as a `Table2ViewController` so we can access its properties. Finally we set its `numberOfSections` property using some method on `Table1ViewController`.

Comment: If you find a reply that is helpful and answers your question, please don't forget to accept it.